# The linear equation $8x_1+7x_2+3x_3=0$ portray a plane, how can you find a parametric equation $x= su + tv$ for this plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Equation $8x_1+14x_2+6x_3=0$ portray a plane through origo $(0,0)$

I want to find a parametric equation in the form of $x=su+tv$ where $u$ and $v$ is vectors. Is it as simple as finding two vectors from three points on the plane? May I ask what the constant-variables $s$ and $t$ should then be? This will just change the size of the vectors, and not the property of the equation and its domain?

Sorry for any misspellings or wrong grammar, english is not my first language. Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it as simple as finding two vectors from three points on the plane?

Yes, it is that easy, and that would be your $u$ and your $v$. Just make sure they aren't parallel.

> May I ask what the constant-variables $s$ and $t$ should then be?

Not constant, for one thing. They would be the parameters of this parametrization. Each possible choice of one value for $s$ and one value for $t$, when inserted into $su + tv$ will result in a single point in the plane. For instance, $1u + 3v$ is a point in the plane, and $13u - 5v$ is also a point in the plane (it even happens to be a *different* point). The collection of all possible choices will together give you the collection of all points on the plane. That's basically what "parametrization" means.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve for one variable. Let's take $x_1$.
We then have
$$8x_1 = -14x_2 - 6x_3 \Leftrightarrow x_1 = -\frac{7}{4}x_2 - \frac{3}{4}x_3.$$
The vector $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}$ has then the form
$$ \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{7}{4}x_2 - \frac{3}{4}x_3 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}  
=
\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{7}{4}x_2 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}
+ \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{3}{4}x_3 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}
= x_2\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{7}{4} \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}}_{u} + x_3\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{3}{4}\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}}_{v}.$$
Set $s := x_2$ and $t := x_3.$ So as you see, $s$ and $t$ are not constants.You scale the basic vectors $u$ and $v$ with them.

Comment: May I ask where you got the $[1,1,0]$ and $[0,1,0]$ vectors from?

Comment: Oh, I miscalculated. Sorry, I will edit my answer.